# Linear functional on $V$ can only depend on $\dim(V)$ vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a normed space and $\varphi:V\to\mathbb{R}$ a linear functional. Is it true that if $n=\dim(V)$ we cannot ever find $v_1,\dots,v_{n+1}$ $n+1$ distinct vectors in $V$ all of the same length ($\|v_i\|=\|v_j\|$) such that $\varphi(v_i)=a$ for some fixed $a\in\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and each $i=1,\dots,n+1$? I tried writing $v_{n+1}=t_1 v_1+\dots + t_n v_n$. Then this could be possible if $t_1+\dots + t_n=1$, but this does not yet fully determine $v_{n+1}$ to be one of the $v_1,\dots, v_n$.

Comment: You should also check that the linear combination has the same norm as $v_1, ... v_n$.

Comment: @NDewolf but that gives only a second equation on the $t_i$'s, right?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for simplicity that $||v_i|| =1$.

Then we get $||v_{n+1}|| \le \sum_{i=1}^n t_i =1$ so we get that there is equality in the triangle inequality, which yields that the $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are dependent, so if you take the $v_i$'s  to be basis vectors, then you are right, such a functional can't exists.

Comment: Does that not require an inner product and Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality?

Comment: @W.Odit what do you mean by "that"? my answer only uses the fact that equality in triangle inequality means linear dependence.